# Collapsing toolbar

Tags: android

Всем добра! Ребята, подскажите пожалуйста, `Collapsing toolbar` поддерживается c `API 15`? или с какой версии Android начинается поддержка сие чуда?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эта штука является частью библиотеки поддержки, так что то ли с 9, то ли с 10 апи.

Comment: А с учётом всяких проблем с библиотеками поддержки на андроиде меньше пятой версии всё время хочется её как минимальную ставить)